# Database query involving username and count

Tags: mysql

I have a table called tbl_users

A broken down version of it for this task

```
id | username | ref
```

I am trying to count the ref column for most entries and order by most to least.

This column displays users. So if there are 10 rows with "User 1" in the ref column it would return User 1 10.

How can I put this together?

EDIT.
I have put together the following query (using the 5 answers, thanks).

Is throwing up an error, saying the query isn't valid basically.

```
$q = "SELECT ref, count(ref) as total_count FROM ".TBL_USERS." WHERE ref != 'NONE' GROUP BY ref ORDER BY total_count DESC";
```

Any ideas why?

ALL FIXED!!

Comment: How about showing some sample data so we don't need to guess what you've got in there? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit:
Hmm. You have 'user 1' in the ref column, and want to count that. check.

Something like this should work?

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(ref) FROM tbl_users
GROUP BY ref
ORDER BY COUNT(ref) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the link provided below

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?97,26993,26993

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT username, COUNT(ref) 
FROM tbl_users
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY COUNT(ref) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ref) AS ref_count FROM tbl_users
    GROUP BY ref
    ORDER by ref_count DESC
```